# How to rewrite specific pages using mod rewrite?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

Assuming that my website homepage is `https://example.com/test-website/`.
What I want to do is to add a query string at the end of the homepage URL and on all pages that start with `https://example.com/test-website/products/` and `https://example.com/test-website/shop/`.

This is my current code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test-website/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test-website/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loc [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%{REQUEST_URI}/?loc=%{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} [NC,NE,R,L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My code works fine and adds the 'loc' query string parameter to the homepage URL and to all pages on wp-admin but it doesn't work on any other pages on the frontend like `https://example.com/test-website/products/`. The page just opens normally but without the query string.

I tried to remove the following from my code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test-website/index.php [L]
```

This resulted in making the homepage and wp-admin to still work fine but any other pages on the frontend to give 404 error.

Hope you can help me solve this issue, especially that I don't have experience in regex or mod_rewrite.

Comment: To clarify, your WordPress URLs actually contain the `/test-website` URL-path segment? Is your `.htaccess` file in the document root or in the `/test-website` directory?

Comment: @MrWhite all the files are inside ```/test-website``` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is an (external) *redirect*, not an (internal) "rewrite" as stated in your question title. (If you wanted a "rewrite" then you would not use `.htaccess` for this on a WordPress site.)

Also, you shouldn't be modifying the WordPress directives inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block - this is managed by WordPress and is likely to be overridden when WP updates (or at least it will try to).

> I tried to remove the following from my code

The code you are trying to remove is part of the WordPress front-controller. If you remove that then pretty permalinks will not work and your site will likely break. (ie. Pages in the frontend won't resolve and you'll get a 404.)

You've basically put your redirect directives in the wrong place. By placing them after the WP front-controller they simply won't get processed for any "frontend" URLs (except for the homepage, which isn't caught by the preceding front-controller on the first pass). They need to go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` block near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

However, your directives are not specifically checking the URL-paths you want to redirect. ie. the homepage, `/test-website/products/` and `/test-website/shop/`. Your generic regex `.*` matches *everything*!?

Assuming your `.htaccess` is located in the `/test-website` subdirectory then try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loc [NC]
RewriteRule ^($|products/|shop/) /%{REQUEST_URI}/?loc=%{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} [NC,NE,R,L,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

*Aside:* Do you really want to unconditionally append a trailing slash to the URL-path?

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it seems to be working perfectly, I have one more question please which i hope you can help me with.
I was wondering how to rewite the url without redirections to be ```https://example.com/test-website/%{REQUEST_URI}/```
and
```https://example.com/test-website/%{REQUEST_URI}/shop/```
i tried to edit the rule and just remove '?loc=' but i ended up having a redirection loop and url looked like ```https://example.com/test-website/EG/EG/EG/EG/...```

and i guess if i solved the loop issue  will get a 404 error

Comment: I know its much easier to do that using php and create a wordpress custom taxonomy but my original goal is to display different woocommerce pricing based on country and avoid the prices to be cached by page caching that's why i used mod_rewrite, so i'm wondering how to achive the same thing that can be done from wp permalink settings using htaccess

sorry for the typo on the prevous comment, i meant the link to be
https://example.com/test-website/%{HTTP:CF-IPCountry}/ and https://example.com/test-website/%{HTTP:CF-IPCountry}/shop/

Comment: It's difficult to _rewrite_ the URL in `.htaccess` when using WordPress, because of the way WordPress routes URLs (it looks at the requested URL, not at the rewritten URL). You would need to do this in WordPress itself. However, if the information is being sent in an HTTP request header then there is really no need to rewrite (or redirect for that matter). Why not just access the `CF-IPCountry` HTTP request header directly in PHP?

Comment: If my answer above answered your initial question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark below the voting arrows on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks so much MrWhite, Sure i accepted your answer wished i can upvote it too :)
The reason i didn't use php to access CF-IPCountry and used rewrite instead is to avoid page caching, i have woocommerce store with prices varies depend on country so if the page got cached when a us visitor visited it all links on the page for uk user will have /us/ on the link. however i though now for a wayy too do it... to add a custom taxonomy that use ```CF-IPCountry``` in php to create the dynamic taxonomy/directories and then use rewite to redirect to those links generated by wordpress.

Comment: "...to avoid page caching" - it really depends how your server-side caching mechanism is implemented. For instance, your cache criteria could be dependent on the `CF-IPCountry` request header, rather than simply the URL. (In a similar way to how the `Vary` HTTP response header controls the browser cache.)

Comment: That sounds very nice, but i'm wondering how to do that, and is it posible to do that in a shared hosting, It would be nice if you refrance any documentation for that kind of dynamic caching that depend on response header